# How to do those edge on this hand warmer?

Tags: modeling

[link file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hAMyXs-l5NAjgytRRv2iKi6eA_u_ridE/view?usp=drive_link)

I'm trying to do those path here :
[image]
[image]

seems like i don't know how to do this on this mesh.. any idea ?
My first idea was to boolean this tube, remesh voxel than decimate but seems like decimate 11 millions faces crash blender..
[[image]]

https://mega.nz/file/oqpDWCKL
key if asked : T9dYD9Ri32FWSs1IwK3ebZv-UY6FnIElAqWhta-YPk4

Comment: That file link requires access to download. If your file is smaller than 30 Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it

Comment: @JohnEason ok i will do it, the file is 4mo

Comment: I added the google drive link and a mega nz link with the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simplify your topology (begin with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*):

[image]

Inset these 4 faces and *LoopTools > Circle*, extrude down to create the button:

[image]

Select the edge loop all around and bevel:

[image]

Extrude down, etc:

[image]

Comment: i'm going to try this solution later, thanks for the answer